# Can't set background color for container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Only the nav container gets its background color, but I want the whole fluid container to be dark.

```css
.dark-nav {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid dark-nav">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark dark-nav navbar-expand-lg container">
    *Navbar content here*
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add bootstrap to your project?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is you don't have any content in container fluid and the best way you can do is

> Try this or add some content

```
.dark-nav {
            background-color: #222;

        }

<div class="container-fluid dark-nav">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark dark-nav navbar-expand-lg container">
        content here
    </nav>
</div>
```

> With some content in container-fluid

```
.dark-nav {
            background-color: #222;
            padding:20px
        }
<div class="container-fluid dark-nav">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark dark-nav navbar-expand-lg container">
        content gjoes heere
    </nav>
    <div>
        some extra content
    </div>
    <div>
        some extra content
    </div>
    <div>
        some extra content
    </div>
    <div>
        some extra content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div` with class `container-fluid` will only take the height of the content present, in your example there is only the `navbar` inside the container. If you want to set the background to the full height of the browser screen you can use the below class.

```
.dark-nav {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also please note, that you need to remove the class `dark-nav` on the navbar, since this is adding the same background to the navbar also!

Please refer the below example!

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.dark-nav {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid dark-nav">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg container">
    *Navbar content here*
  </nav>
</div>
```